# Bower install from URL gives blank folder

Tags: bower, downloadify

I'm using bower (v. 1.3.5) to pull in my Front-End JS dependencies, and I want to depend on this: https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify

It doesn't have its own bower.json so I'm referencing by URL in MY bower.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "jspdf": "~1.0.272",
    "downloadify": "https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify.git"
  }
```

But all I get is the named folder containing only a `.bower.json` file, but none of the code or anything else in the GH repo.

Running bower install directly on the cmd line gave (once I'd cleared out the bower cache):

```
E:/My/Path>bower install https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify.git
bower Downloadify#*        not-cached https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify.git#*
bower Downloadify#*        resolve https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify.git#*
bower Downloadify#*        checkout 0.2.1
bower Downloadify#*        resolved https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify.git#0.2.1
bower Downloadify#~0.2.1   install Downloadify#0.2.1
```

I previously did the same thing with jQuery.fileDownload which worked perfectly, so I don't ***think*** it's anything I've done to my machine?

**QUESTION:**

- Have I done something wrong?
- Has Downloadify been set up wrong?
- Or is it an inexplicable mystery?

In either of the first 2 cases, what is the problem and how do I fix it?

NOTE: Currently I'm working around it by having downloaded the source code manually and having it hard-coded into my project.

Comment: Yes, giving this a bower.json should be my next 24 PR item :)

Comment: Which version of Bower are you using? for me this is working fine

Comment: v 1.3.5 (also added to main question)

Comment: Try updating you Bower version to 1.3.8 or later it should solve the issue